# Checking loop in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops

I have this question about loops.
Imagine You have this data array:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

How would You write a loop which checks if the previous number is lower, and the next after the checked one (Condition looks like this `[5,6,5]`). So the loop will get to number 9 and print it or save it, whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `next` with a generator expression:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

res = next(j for i, j, k in zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:]) if i < j and i == k)
```

If you need all such numbers, use a list comprehension instead:

```
res = [j for i, j, k in zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:]) if i < j and i == k]
```

If you need a condition that will show all numbers that are higher than their previous and next ones:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,6]

res = [j for i, j, k in zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:]) if i < j > k]
```

`[4, 3, 2, 8]` is printed.

**Explanation**

- You can iterate the list with shifted versions of itself via `zip`.
- For each triplet, test your two conditions.
- Use `next` to extract such triplets; if no such triplet exists, you will meet `StopIteration` error.
- Never name a variable after a built-in, e.g. use `lst` instead of `list`.

Comment: Thank You so much for that explanation. Well, my problem is much more complex. Can I ask You to check my other thread? Maybe You'll have some ideas for that problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647094/checking-array-data-by-a-loop-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a simple loop that checks the previous number is less than the current number, and the next number is equal to the previous number:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i-1] < lst[i] and lst[i-1] == lst[i+1]:
        print(lst[i])

# 9
```